# Google Timeline error - "Can't connect to Maps, try again later" only on certain dates

Tags: google-maps

I have been using Google timeline successfully for many months without problem but in the last few days I have getting this error on all my devices (phone, tablet and desktop) **but only on some dates**

[image: error on one date]
[image: OK on different date]

Comment: Are you sure there is no problem with your Internet connection?

Comment: The problem only shows when viewing certain dates Writchik as I showex in the two images above. I suspected that it was a data issue so I contacted Google and they reset something and I can now view all dates ok. If you get this problem view your timeline for a different date and if the problem only shows on some dates then I suggest you contact Google Maps support - they were very helpful as none of these message boards seems to have a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that it was a data issue as it only affected  some dates so I contacted Google Maps support and they reset something. I can now view all my dates ok. If you get this problem view your timeline for a different date and if the problem only shows on some dates then I suggest you contact Google Maps support - they were very helpful as none of these message boards seems to have a reliable solution.